# Looking for a replacement spline for my cabinets

Tags: cabinets, glass, custom-cabinetry

We are having our kitchen cabinets painted white and need to replace the spline that holds in the glass on 4 of the cabinet doors. Unfortunately we don't have a physical sample anymore but I have these pictures.

Any idea on where we can buy these? There are a lot of options and most of them say they are for aluminum windows, but this goes into a groove in a wooden cabinet door.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the photos are not a physical sample then what context do they provide. Maybe a photo of the cabinet door where the glass needs to be affixed.

Comment: @AlaskaMan they are pictures of the exact old spline, I just didn't have it physically anymore so I couldn't measure it. But I was able to find a piece.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are dozens and dozens (hundreds? thousands?) of types and shapes of "spline" material.

I recommend that you do NOT go on a "goose chase" for an exact duplicate of what was installed previously. Instead, I recommend that you take a door and glass pane with you to a local window/door/glass shop and find any alternative that will adequately secure the glass. There are even newer foam strip materials that conform to a variety of channel sizes and shapes. You could even consider "non-spline" alternatives like nailed wood strips or plastic clips.

- it does not matter what the labeled use of the spline is, as long as it securely holds the pane
- it does not matter what the material is, as long as it securely holds the pane

Comment: Thanks yea we may have to end up doing that. We've already tried about 4 different glass shops and they either wanted more than the door is worth or they were going to use metal clips. I found something that looks similar on Amazon so I'm going to give that a try, otherwise we will probably go with the metal clips and maybe caulk over the kerf cut

Comment: Caulking is probably not a good idea, BTW. If the pane breaks you will *never* be able to remove it (or the pieces of it) without extreme difficulty. If anything, use a non-setting caulking putty. I really highly recommend non-adhesive foam strip, often found in the weatherstrip aisle; not the soft mushy stuff but open-cell round foam, that you can stuff in the channel.